# Can I combine INT boosting Cognatogens with Fox's Cunning?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

I am trying to build an Pathfinder Alchemist and ran into a question I'm having trouble answering: **Can I combine the effects of an INT boosting Cognatogen with a Fox's Cunning potion?**

Comment: Hello, and welcome to RPG.SE!  Generally, our format doesn't work very well when you ask about several different things in one question.  You're asking about three very different things here, and you'll probably get better answers if you split your question in 3.  You might also want to check out the [tour] and [help], for more information on the site.

Comment: I've removed the second question, since it's still distinct from the remainder. You _should_ ask these separately. You can still access them via your [revision history](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/59763/revisions), which you can access by clicking the 'edited X time ago' link beneath your question.

Comment: Current version is no longer unclear, though it is a possible duplicate of every other "does X stack with Y" question we've ever had, as the answer to any one of them pretty much clears up the rest of them as well.

Answer (score 6):

The Cognatogen stacks with Fox's Cunning. Beyond the stats it affects, a Cognatogen "works just like the mutagen ability," quoth the [Cognatogen entry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/cognatogen-su). The [Mutagen](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Mutagen-Su-) passage states that it's an alchemical bonus, and the Cognatogen entry doesn't note any change in bonus type. [Fox's Cunning](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fox-s-cunning) is an enhancement bonus, so they stack, per standard stacking rules.